# Short story, “Seven Century Summer”, where man has an accident and time travels to a future post apocalyptic world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a science fiction short story I believe is titled “Seven Century Summer” or something like that. From what I remember a modern man had an accident and traveled forward in time, to a post apocalyptic world. There his consciousness inhabited the mind of a native. There was a great being in a tank of some sort.

Answer (score 11):

I literally read this yesterday and thought that it fits.

**Midsummer Century (1972)
(A book in the Haertel Scholium series)
A novel by James Blish**

> In the year 25,000 A.D . . . When John Martels returned to consciousness he found himself the Delphic Oracle of a world far different from the Twentieth Century. Humanity had risen and fallen three times and was back once again in a semi-primitive state. He shared his oracular powers with a mind and a device left over from the last Rebirth . . . but the real problem was not rebuilding civilization, it was that another genus of creatures had arisen to claim inheritance of the world--the evolved, strangely intelligent birds, whose priority was the elimination of the world's former masters.

This book actually contains one novella-length story, “Midsummer Century,” and two short stories: “Skysign” and “A Style in Treason".

As pointed out by user14111 the short story is [available](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v042n04_1972-04/page/n3) on the internet archive.

Comment: Please add a link to where you quoted thIs from. It's good practice anyway, plus I want to see what they think is in the series.

Comment: Am I missing something? I can't see deleted answers; was there originally an answer by the OP?

Comment: @MrLister - Presumably now deleted by User14111. And since that's the case, this whole comment chain can now be flagged as outdated/no longer needed.

Comment: Probably abusing local norms, as I have no idea of the apripriate etiquette on this site. That said, I love you. Thank you lol